# - (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData not called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp

```
 -(void)setupStream 
{
xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];

[xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
xmppStream.startTLSPolicy = XMPPStreamStartTLSPolicyRequired;

[xmppStream setHostName:@"37.247.116.191"];

[xmppStream setHostPort:5222];

}
```

After connecting to host this delegates method not called:

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
```

Comment: i m not using pod to install XMPP Framework....I have done it by manually setup added suff. folders??Plz help me

Comment: how do i call     - (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag

Comment: when I send <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='localhost'>
to server......then i dont receive any response from didReadData......plz help me

Comment: i dont know how to do this.....thanks